# Good manual about file uploading with flash

Tags: flash, uploader

I am gonna make my own flash file-uploader, but I can't find any good materials. It would be nice if somebody will give me a link to manual regarding how to make a simple flash uploader, but I'll appreciate any responses and suggestions. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What technologies are you using other than Flash? I'm going to assume PHP.

A good place to start would be to check out the [AS3 FileReference documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html).

[Here is a decent tutorial](http://www.permadi.com/blog/2010/06/flash-using-filereference-and-php-to-upload-files-to-server/) that may be helpful to get started.

And [this site](http://www.google.com) is usually pretty detailed. (Sorry, couldn't help myself :)